# syslog-ng.conf under SLES 12

Tags: syslog, sles

Where can I find the syslog config file under SLES 12?

`rsyslog` and `syslog-service` are installed according to YaST2 and `rcsyslog status` outputs:

```
ServerName:~ # rcsyslog status
Usage: /sbin/rcsyslog {start|stop|status|try-restart|restart|force-reload|reload}
rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-03-04 16:05:46 CET; 1 day 17h ago
 Main PID: 787 (rsyslogd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
           ââ787 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

Comment: Syslog-ng is included in SLES 12, but you'll need to enable to SLES 12 Legacy module to get at it.

Answer (score 0):

Found out, that SLES 12 doesn't use `syslog-ng` anymore.

It now uses `rsyslog` which has it's config file under `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue using syslog-ng, the latest package is available at https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:czanik:syslog-ng36/

Answer (score 0):

We have an rsyslog on SLES 12 instead of syslog-ng. And we have an configuration file in /etc/rsyslog.d/remote.conf where you could define thr syslog server to which you want to connect. And we have /etc/rsylog.conf for rest of the configuration related to rsyslog.